# Update mongo array field from angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I have this jade file:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="lineas in datuak">
    <td class="tdlinea">Linea:{{ lineas.linea }}</td>
    <td data-ng-repeat="nireindex in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
      <table class="table text-center table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <th>Mañana</th>
          <th>Tarde</th>
          <th>Noche</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tr ng-repeat="orden in lineas.egunak[nireindex].turnoak[0].ordenes" ng-if="checkStatus(lineas.egunak[nireindex].fetxa,nireindex)">
                    <td style="background-color: {{ mysettings | searchByRefBackcolor : 'ref' : orden.ref }} !important; color:{{ mysettings | searchByRefForecolor : 'ref' : orden.ref }} !important;">
                        <span editable-text="orden.ref" onbeforesave="updateUser($data)">{{ orden.ref }}</span><span editable-text="orden.of">{{ orden.of }}</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tr ng-repeat="orden in lineas.egunak[nireindex].turnoak[1].ordenes" ng-if="checkStatus(lineas.egunak[nireindex].fetxa,nireindex)">
                    <td style="background-color: {{ mysettings | searchByRefBackcolor : 'ref' : orden.ref }} !important; color:{{ mysettings | searchByRefForecolor : 'ref' : orden.ref }} !important;">{{ orden.ref }} {{ orden.of }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tr ng-repeat="orden in lineas.egunak[nireindex].turnoak[2].ordenes" ng-if="checkStatus(lineas.egunak[nireindex].fetxa,nireindex)"><td style="background-color: {{ mysettings | searchByRefBackcolor : 'ref' : orden.ref }} !important; color:{{ mysettings | searchByRefForecolor : 'ref' : orden.ref }} !important;">{{ orden.ref }} {{ orden.of }}</td></tr>
                </table>
              </td>                             
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr> <!-- lineas -->
</tbody>
```

And I implemented onclick edit feature with http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/ all workf fine instead when I´m going to update this field.

My database is in mongodb and looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "linea": 1,
        "egunak": [
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/26",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF000013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": 112233
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/27"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/28",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF200013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF232233"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF289977"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/29"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/30"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/31"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/06/01"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "linea": 2,
        "egunak": [
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/26"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/27",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00002"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF000013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF2233"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/28"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/29",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF200013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF232233"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/30"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/31"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/06/01"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I update for example linea:1 => fetxa: "2014/05/26" => turno:2 => ref :"3CI00001" (the second one) to ref:3CI00002 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller.js from example  http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/ for Editable table

```
  $scope.saveTable = function() {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = $scope.users.length; i--;) {
      var user = $scope.users[i];
      // ...
      // send on server
      results.push($http.post('/saveUser', user));      
    }

    return $q.all(results);
  };
});
```

As you can see, each user saved on server side with all user fields. The easiest way is update full object on server side without building update query for few fields.